# How can I get this to print the character value?

Tags: java

```
public static String convertPNumber(String p) {
    String b;
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length(); i++) {
        char a = p.charAt(i);
        if (!Character.isDigit(a)) {
            if (a == 'A' || a == 'B' || a == 'C') {
                b = "2";
            }
        } else {
            b = a;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    convertPNumber("AB2");
}
```

I want it to print the digit if the character is a digit, but since the method is public static String, it says String is required when b = a; and it found char.

Comment: Erm...your edit made our answers invalid.  If you have another question to ask, please ask it in another question.  Otherwise, this edit may get reverted.

Comment: Go ahead and revert, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` is a type of `String`.  `a` is a type of `char`.  You cannot assign a primitive such as `char` to a `String`.

What you *can* do is use [`Character.toString(char value)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29) instead:

```
b = Character.toString(a);
```

I'm also noticing that you've got a few deficiencies in your program...but I'll leave the major logic issue for you to fix.

When you go to fix the above issue, there is a chance that the `for` statement is not executed, so the variable `b` may not be initialized.  You can fix this by initializing `b` to `null`.

Your logic is unusual - you only ever pay attention to the last character in your `String`, and I'm not entirely sure that's what you want.  Figured I'd point that out for you.

Comment: I'm in intro to Java class, so my logic is kind of dumb and unconventional and honestly probably wrong. This was an unfinished code, I finished it now and am editing it to contain my finished code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking each character in your string, and converting it into another character.  But, you don't put those characters together at all.  One way to do this, but not necessarily the most efficient, is to use the `StringBuilder` class.  That class is designed to be a mutable `String`.

I won't write the innermost method, but here's a start.

```
public class ABTranslator {
    public String translate(String before) {
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0, length = before.length(); i < length; i++) {
            char a = before.charAt(i);
            b.append(convert(a));
        }
        return b.toString();
    }

    public char convert(char before) {
        // You write this.
    }
}
```

You can use regular expressions instead of your `if` code above.

Now, write a set of JUnit tests to check whether your methods are correct:

```
//In ABTranslatorTest.java

@Before
public void initTranslator() {
    this.translator = new ABTranslator();
}

@Test
public void digitsAreConvertedToThemselves() {
    Assert.assertEquals('3', translator.convert('3');
}

@Test
public void mostCharsAreConvertedToThemselves() {
    Assert.assertEquals('X', translator.convert('X');
}

@Test
public void ABCAreConvertedToTwo() {
    Assert.assertEquals('B', translator.convert('2');
}

@Test
public void WordsAreConvertedAsCharactersAre() {
    Assert.assertEquals("222", translator.translate("AB2");
}
```

Make all of these work.  Find out from your colleagues how to set up JUnit 4.11.  Note that I made all the methods non-static.  If you don't have experience with that, write a main method.  Still, that should be your only `static` method.